# ANT landscape material bug

Tags: add-on

Trying to use ANT landscape. It work fine but after i change settings it turns black as it has some strange material settings. 
I can use landscape after i change the material, but it really hard to change landscape. Cant see anything when it is black like this.
[image]

[image: after changing setting subdivision x by 1]

Comment: Try changing the position of your **Lamp**.

Comment: There is no lamp. It is not render view. It is solid.

Comment: Try adding a lamp